# Barrett Reduction - Possible without overflow and floating point arithmetic?

Tags: modular-arithmetic, arithmetic

I have two variables, $x$ and $y$. I'm looking to compute the product of $x$ and $y$ modulo $p$, where $p$ is prime.

For small values of $x$ and $y$ (less than 43 bits each), I was able to perform the computation using [Barrett Reduction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Barrett_reduction).

However, for large values of $x$ and $y$, overflow exceeding 128 bits occurs, and the computed value is incorrect. This is because $x$ and $y$ must be multiplied together, which must be stored in a 128-bit datatype. That product must then be multiplied by a precomputed constant, $r$, resulting in a value that can be stored in 192 bits.

Is it possible to compute `xy mod p` using Barrett Reduction where overflow over 128 bits **does not** occur, also while not relying on floating point arithmetic?

If it helps, I have the ability to perform the multiplication of $x$ and $y$ and store the product in two variables: $a$ and $b$, where $a$ holds the high 64 bits of the product, and $b$ holds the low 64 bits of the product.

Comment: How large is $p$? Is it greater than $43$ bits?

Comment: @DavidK $p$ won't exceed 64 bits.

Comment: The obvious first step is to take `x mod p` and `y mod p` before doing the multiplication--but if $p$ is larger than both $x$ and $y$, that won't help.

Comment: @DavidK Yes, $p$ is already larger than both $x$ and $y$.

Comment: So the overflow you mention occurs only when you multiply by $r$?

Comment: @DavidK Yes, the intermediate value, `x * y * r`, is too large to fit in 128 bits, so I’m curious if it’s possible to reduce it somehow

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, but in addition to $r = \left\lfloor \dfrac{2^{64}}p\right\rfloor$, you will also need $$s =\left\lfloor \dfrac{2^{128}}p\right\rfloor - 2^{64}r$$
and $$t = 2^{64} - rp$$
Note that $s,t < 2^{64}$.

So you have $xy = a2^{64} + b$. Then 
$$\begin{align}xy \bmod p &= (a2^{64} + b) \bmod p\\&= \big[(a2^{64}\bmod p) + (b\bmod p)\big]\bmod p\end{align}$$

Per Barrett's algorithm, to calculate $a2^{64}\bmod p$, you first calculate
$$q = \left\lfloor\dfrac {a2^{64}(2^{24}r + s)}{2^{128}}\right\rfloor = ar + \left\lfloor\frac{as}{2^{64}}\right\rfloor$$

The approximate modulus is then
$$2^{64}a - qp = a(2^{64} - rp) - \left\lfloor\frac{as}{2^{64}}\right\rfloor p= at - \left\lfloor\frac{as}{2^{64}}\right\rfloor p$$

In pseudocode, to find $x \bmod p$ for a 128-bit $x$

```
function Mod128(x, p)
   a = x >> 64
   b = x - (a << 64)
   qa = a * s >> 64
   qb = b * r >> 64
   a1 = a * t - qa * p
   if a1 >= p then a1 = a1 - p
   b1 = b - qb * p
   if b1 >= p then b1 = b1 - p
   x1 = a1 + b1
   if x1 >= p then x1 = x1 - p
   return x1
```

Variation assuming two functions `hi64(x,y)` and `lo64(x,y)` that return the high and low 64 bits of the product of 64 bit integers `x` and `y`. If $p <2^{63}$, this version is guaranteed to never overflow using unsigned 64 bit arithmetic, since `qb * p` can be at most `b`:

```
function ModProd(x,y,p)
   a = hi64(x,y)
   b = lo64(x,y)
   qa = hi64(a,s)
   qb = hi64(b,r)
   at = lo64(a,t)
   qap = lo64(qa,p)
   if at < qap then 
      a1 = (2^63 - qap) + 2^63 + at
   else
      a1 = at - qap
   if a1 >= p then a1 = a1 - p
   b1 = b - qb * p
   if b1 >= p then b1 = b1 - p
   prod = a1 + b1
   if prod >= p then prod = prod - p
   return prod
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. How would the pseudocode change if `x` was stored in two 64-bit variables instead? One variable would be the high 64 bits of the product, and the other would be the low 64 bits.

Comment: The first two lines divide $x$ up into the high 64 bits $a$ and low 64 bits $b$. Everything after that is in 64 bits (except the products before the >> 64 shift is applied - but that is just taking the high 64 bits of that product)

Comment: I added a version that uses only 64 bit arithmetic, except for two functions for returning the high and low 64 bits of products.

Comment: Much appreciated. I’ll be able to verify that everything works in a couple hours, and then I’ll be happy to accept this answer. Thanks again!

Comment: Actually, it needed a little more cleaning before I can claim it is 64-bit arithmetic only, as `a * t` and `qa * p` are not guaranteed to be below 2^64. However, since their difference is guaranteed to be so(assuming $2p <2^{64}$), the high 64 bits must be the same, and can be discarded.

Comment: After a little more examination, I decided that were cases possible where `hi64(a * t) = hi64(qa * p) + 1`. The easiest way to fix that was to check if `a * t` was less than `qa * p` after discarding the high 64 bits, and to add 2^64 to the difference in this case.

Comment: How can I calculate `r`, `s` and `t` using only 64-bit operations? Should I make it a separate question? For a 64-bit version of the Barrett reduction that I created, I calculate `r` as `((2^64)-1) / p`, which gives me the same results as long as `p` is not a power of 2. But the other two (`s` and `t`) are a bit more complicated, so I'm not sure where to start...